# Limit Supremum / finite limit meaning

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

I'm a little confused about the definition of limit supremum; what does it mean that the following limit is finite?

$$\limsup _{h\rightarrow \infty}\;\sup_{x\in \mathbb R}\; A(x,h)$$
where $A(x,h)$ is a function of $x$, and $h$.

Comment: Does it mean anything?  Looks to me like you're binding $h$ twice.  Did you mean something like $\displaystyle \limsup_{h \to \infty}\ \sup_{x \in \mathbb R}\ A(x,h)$?

Comment: Exactly, but I have no idea how to make it like this!

Comment: You can right-click the expression in my comment and select "Show Source" to see how I did it.

Comment: There are many different ways of defining the limit superior; one of them is the following: the limit superior is the supremum of the set of limit points.

Comment: This question seems to be related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49699/about-the-notion-of-limsup-and-liminf/

Answer (score 2):

It means that there exists some finite $H$ and $C$ such that for every $h\ge H$ and every $x$ in $\mathbb R$, $A(x,h)\le C$.

Proof:

If $H$ and $C$ as above exist, then $\limsup\limits_{h\to+\infty}\,\sup\limits_{x\in\mathbb R}A(x,h)\le C$ hence it is finite.

To prove the other direction, first recall that, for any function $B$ and any finite $c$, $\limsup\limits_{h\to+\infty}\,B(h)\le c$ means that, for every $c'>c$, there exists a finite $h_0$ such that $B(h)\le c'$ for every $h\ge h_0$.

Hence  $\limsup\limits_{h\to+\infty}\,B(h)$ is finite if and only if there exists some finite $C$ and $H$ such that $B(h)\le C$ for every $h\ge H$.

Apply this to $B(h)=\sup\limits_{x\in\mathbb R}A(x,h)$, hence $B(h)\le C$ for every $h\ge H$. Now, $A(x,h)\le B(h)$ for every $x$ in $\mathbb R$ and  $B(h)\le C$ for every $h\ge H$, hence $A(x,h)\le C$ for every $h\ge H$ and $x$ in $\mathbb R$.

Done.