# Proof of $\lim\sup(a_nb_n)\leq \lim\sup(a_n)\limsup(b_n)$

Tags: analysis, limits, inequality, limsup-and-liminf

Let $a_n>0$ and $b_n\geq 0$, then $\lim\sup(a_nb_n)\leq \lim\sup(a_n)\limsup(b_n)$

My attempt at a proof is as follows.  Let $A_n=\sup\{a_n, a_{n+1},...\}$, $B_n=\sup\{b_n, b_{n+1},...\}$, and $C_n=\sup\{a_nb_n, a_{n+1}b_{n+1},...\}$.

Note: $a_mb_m \leq A_nB_n$ for all $m \geq n$.

Thus $\limsup(a_nb_n)=\lim C_n \leq \lim (A_nB_n) = (\lim A_n)(\lim B_n) = (\limsup a_n)(\limsup b_n).$

Comment: Looks good to me. What is your question?

Comment: Is this proof even reasonable?  That is, I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: If you want to be super picky, to say $\lim(A_nB_n)=(\lim A_n)(\lim B_n)$, you need to first show the two individual limits exist. Of course this was probably done in defining what a limsup is in the first place.

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: the limit of products factors into the product of limits iff both individual limits $\lim A_n$ and $\lim B_n$ exist by themselves. As a contradiction, consider:

$1=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{n}{n}\neq (\lim n)(\lim \frac{1}{n})=undetermined$

Comment: The missing argument is that $(A_n)$ and $(B_n)$ are nonnegative (here) nonincreasing (always) sequences.

Comment: See also [lim sup inequality $\limsup ( a_n b_n ) \leq \limsup a_n \limsup b_n $](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/113121)

Answer (score 2):

Missing pieces:

1. You need to assume the sequences are bounded. Otherwise the statement may be even nonsensical: how to interpret $1\le 0\cdot \infty$, for example?
2. $(A_n)$ and $(B_n)$ are nonnegative   nonincreasing  sequences; these properties imply the existence of the limits $\lim A_n$ and $\lim B_n$, which allows to conclude about the existence and the value of  $\lim (A_nB_n)$.

You could have assumed $a_n\ge 0$ instead of $a_n>0$.