# proof that $\limsup a_n=\sup\{a_n,a_{n+1},...\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, limsup-and-liminf

How can I prove that $\limsup a_n= \sup\{a_n,a_{n+1},...\}$?

I also need to prove:  for two sequences $a_n>0$ and $b_n \ge 0$, then $\limsup(a_n b_n) \le \limsup(a_n) \limsup(b_n)$.

I thought that instead I can prove $\limsup a_n=\sup\{s|s \text{ is a sub-limit of } a_n\}=\sup\{a_n,a_{n+1},...\}$

Comment: This is not true. You should work differently toward the goal.

Comment: Please [format your question so that it is readable](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: See [Proof of $\lim\sup(a_nb_n)\leq \lim\sup(a_n)\limsup(b_n)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/197858), but note the presence of $\lim C_n$ there, not just $C_n$.

Comment: @navehporat perhaps you mean to show
$$
\limsup a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup \{a_n,a_{n+1}, \dots\}?
$$
If so, then what is your definition of the limsup of a sequence?

Comment: @navehporat We can't help you prove any of these statements until you tell us which of the several equivalent definitions of the limsup you're starting from

Comment: you're right, this makes more sence.

Comment: the definition that I was given is $limsupa_n=sup{s|s\:is\:a sub limit of  (a_n)}$

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know how to format, I'll learn

Comment: Are you using Rudin by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quick approach, using the equivalent definition:**

We have
$$
\limsup_{n \to \infty} a_n b_n = 
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{m \geq n} a_m b_m
=
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{m=m',m \geq n} a_m b_{m'} \leq\\
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{m,m' \geq n} a_m b_{m'} = 
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\sup_{m \geq n} a_m b_{m'}\right)
\left(\sup_{m' \geq n} a_m b_{m'}\right) =\\
 \left(\lim_{n \to \infty}\sup_{m \geq n} a_m b_{m'}\right)
\left(\lim_{n \to \infty}\sup_{m' \geq n} a_m b_{m'}\right)=\\
\limsup a_n \cdot \limsup b_n
$$

---

**Using the sublimit definition:**

Let $a = \limsup \{a_n\}$ and $b = \limsup \{b_n\}$.
Consider an arbitrary convergent subsequence $a_{n_k}b_{n_k}$ of $\{a_nb_n\}$.  If we can show that
$$
\lim_{k \to \infty} a_{n_k} b_{n_k} \leq a \cdot b
$$
then we'd be able to say that $a \cdot b$ is an upper-bound to the set of all sublimits of $a_n b_n$.  So, by the definition of a supremum, we could deduce that
$$
\limsup(a_n b_n) \le \limsup(a_n) \limsup(b_n)
$$
Which is what we want.

---

To prove that this is the case, we could proceed as follows: let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary.  Let $L = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n_k}b_{n_k}$, noting that $L \leq \limsup(a_n b_n)$.  There exists a $K$ such that for $k > K$, we have:

- $a_k b_k \geq L - \epsilon$
- $a_k \leq a + \epsilon$
- $b_k \leq b + \epsilon$

In particular, we have (for any such $k$)
$$
L - \epsilon \leq a_k b_k \leq (a+\epsilon)(b+\epsilon)
$$
Noting that $\epsilon > 0$ was arbitrary, we conclude that $L \leq ab$, as desired.

Comment: The convergence of $a_{n_k}b_{n_k}$ does not imply the convergence of individual factors.

Comment: Well, that's an oversight.  Good point

Comment: ...Fixed it now