# $\sup_{n >k}a_n \sup_{n>k}b_n = \sup_{m,n > k} a_nb_m \geq \sup_{n > k} a_nb_n$

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

I'm considering the proof written by robjohn in the following post:

[lim sup inequality $\limsup ( a_n b_n ) \leq \limsup a_n \limsup b_n $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113121/lim-sup-inequality-limsup-a-n-b-n-leq-limsup-a-n-limsup-b-n)

Now, in that proof, he says that $$\sup_{n >k}a_n \sup_{n>k}b_n = \sup_{m,n > k} a_nb_m \geq \sup_{n > k} a_nb_n$$ by monotonicity of the sup function. How does he get the first equality sign and why the change of variable to $m$? And how does he get the second inequality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second inequality is true because the size of the set over which the supremum is searched, has been reduced, i.e. 
$$
\{a_nb_n, {n > k}\} \subseteq\{a_nb_m, {m,n > k} \}
$$
so the supremum of first set is less than or equal to the supremum of the second set.

To see the first equality, see that (assuming positive values) for $n,m>k$
$$
a_nb_m\leq \sup_{n >k}a_n \sup_{n>k}b_n 
$$
Therefore:
$$  \sup_{m,n > k} a_nb_m \leq\sup_{n >k}a_n \sup_{n>k}b_n$$
On the other hand for each $a_i$ we have:
$$ 
\frac{ \sup_{m,n > k} a_nb_m} {\sup_{n>k}b_n}  \geq \frac{ \sup_{n=i,m > k} a_ib_m} {\sup_{n>k}b_n} =a_i 
$$
and hence:
$$
\sup_{n >k}a_n\leq \frac{ \sup_{m,n > k} a_nb_m} {\sup_{n>k}b_n}  
$$
which proves that:
$$
\sup_{n >k}a_n \sup_{n>k}b_n = \sup_{m,n > k} a_nb_m 
$$

Comment: Amazing. Nice constructions with sup :) Feel like I gotta do some sup gymnastics.