# Limit superior of product of two sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

I'm an undergraduate mathematics student and I'm trying to understand the basics of limes superior. I recently got stuck on the following question:

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of numbers and let $(b_n)$ be a sequence of numbers with $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=1$.
Show:

1) $$\lim\limits \sup (b_na_n)=\lim\limits \sup a_n$$
      2) $$\lim\limits \sup (a_n^{b_n})=\lim\limits \sup a_n$$

My first thought on trying to solve problem 1) was to try and show that $\lim\limits \sup (b_na_n)$ = $\lim\limits \sup (b_n) * \lim\limits \sup (a_n)$, because then I can use the fact that $\lim\limits \sup (b_n) = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n = 1$, and that would be sufficient. If it's possible to show it this way, I think the second problem would be solvable in a similar fashion. However I'm not really sure how to show this and I don't even know if I'm thinking in the right direction. Anyone mind helping me out on this one?

Comment: The second statement follows from the first upon taking logarithms (and remembering that limits commute with continuous functions).

Comment: Do you mean I should take the log of $\lim\limits \sup (a_n^{b_n})$ ?

Comment: For any positive sequence $c_n$, the lim sup of $\log c_n$ is the same as the logarithm of the lim sup of $c_n$. - Also, you conjectured that $\limsup a_nb_n = \limsup a_n \times \limsup b_n$, and that's a reasonable thought, but it turns out to be wrong. Consider for example $a_n = 1 + (-1)^n$ and $b_n = 1 - (-1)^n$.

Comment: For positive sequences you have $\liminf a_n \cdot \limsup a_n \le \limsup (a_nb_n) \le \limsup a_n \cdot \limsup b_n$. See this question and references given there: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113121/lim-sup-inequality-limsup-a-n-b-n-leq-limsup-a-n-limsup-b-n (The equality does not hold in general, I think it is not very difficult to find counterexamples; you might try some sequences consisting only of 0's and 1's.)

Answer (score 1):

By definition of limit:

$\forall\epsilon>0\ \  \exists n(\epsilon)\in{\Bbb N}\ \ \forall n>n(\epsilon)\ \ 1-\epsilon < b_n < 1+\epsilon$.

Do the same for $\lim\sup a_n$ (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior) and use the inequalities on $b_n$ and $a_n$.