# If $(\limsup_{n\to\infty} x_{n})\cdot(\limsup_{n\to\infty} 1/x_{n})=1$, then the sequence $x_n$ converges

Tags: real-analysis

${x_{n}}$ is a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ where $n\geq 1$ such that all $x_{n} >0$. If 
$(\limsup_{n\to\infty} x_{n})\cdot(\limsup_{n\to\infty} 1/x_{n})=1$, how can I show that ${x_n}$ converges? I am thinking about using the contrapositive  of the statement but I'm not sure if that's the best way. Thank you.

Comment: The linked question may not appear to be a duplicate based on its title, but look at the "there's an equality iff" in the body.

Answer (score 0):

If $x_n$ doesn’t converge then

$$\limsup x_n=L\neq \liminf x_n=l$$

then

$$\limsup \frac1{x_n}=\frac 1 l$$

and

$$\limsup x_n\cdot \limsup \frac1{x_n}\neq1$$

Refer also to

- [Proving $\limsup\frac 1 {a_n}=\frac 1 {\liminf a_n}$ and $\limsup a_n\cdot \limsup \frac 1 {a_n} \ge 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/842764/505767)

Answer (score 0):

(Needs some explanation, but...)
$$
1 = (\limsup_{n\to\infty} x_{n})\cdot(\limsup_{n\to\infty} 1/x_{n})=
\frac{\limsup_{n\to\infty} x_{n}}{\liminf_{n\to\infty} x_{n}}
$$
so
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} x_{n} = \liminf_{n\to\infty} x_{n}
$$
and therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_{n}$ exists.

**added**
Note: Even if
$$
\frac{\limsup_{n\to\infty} x_{n}}{\liminf_{n\to\infty} x_{n}} = \frac{\infty}{\infty}\quad\text{or}\quad
\frac{\limsup_{n\to\infty} x_{n}}{\liminf_{n\to\infty} x_{n}} = \frac{0}{0}
$$
we may still conclude
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} x_{n} = \liminf_{n\to\infty} x_{n}
$$
and therefore that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$ exists in $[0,\infty]$.

Answer (score 0):

$x_n=\frac 1 {\frac 1 {x_n}}$. So $\lim \inf x_n =\lim \inf \frac 1 {\frac 1 {x_n}}=\frac 1 {\lim \sup \frac 1 {x_n}}=\lim \sup x_n$. Hence $(x_n)$ converges.