# limsup of the product of two sequences, of which one converges

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

> Let $\{a_n\}_{n=1 }^{\infty}$ and $\{b_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} $ be two sequences in $\mathbb{R}$, with the first sequence convergent . Prove that   $$ \limsup\limits_{n\to \infty}  a_n b_n =\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n  \limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} b_n$$

I tried following:
$ \limsup\limits_{n\to \infty}  a_n b_n \leq \limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n  \limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} b_n$.
Since $\{a_n\}$ is convergent, $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n =\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n $ gives one  inequality along with one of  the property of the limsup of the product of two sequences i.e 
$ \limsup\limits_{n\to \infty}  a_n b_n \leq \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n  \limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} b_n$.
I want to prove 
$ \limsup\limits_{n\to \infty}  a_n b_n \geq \limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n  \limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} b_n$.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Don't you mean $\limsup_{n\to\infty}$?

Comment: It's not true unless $\lim a_n\geq 0$. Even then, if $\lim a_n=0$ you'll need $\limsup b_n<+\infty$ for the right hand side to be well-defined.

Comment: And everywhere you've written $x\to\infty$, it should be $n\to\infty$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [lim sup inequality $\limsup ( a_n b_n ) \leq \limsup a_n \limsup b_n $](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113121/lim-sup-inequality-limsup-a-n-b-n-leq-limsup-a-n-limsup-b-n)  (the equality case is also treated there)

Comment: @Thursday Depends on how he corrects his question, but he's looking for equality in a specific case.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews which is also proved there

Comment: Kind of remarkable that it was proven, since it is not true.

Comment: Sorry about the typos.

Answer (score 12):

It's not true.

Let $a_n=-1$ for all $n$, and let $b_n=(-1)^n$. Then $a_nb_n=(-1)^{n+1}$ so $$\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_nb_n = 1\\\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=-1\\\limsup_{n\to\infty} b_n=1$$

It is true if $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n > 0$.

If $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n<0$ then the result is:

$$\limsup a_nb_n = \lim a_n \liminf b_n$$

If $\lim a_n = 0$, it gets more complicated.