# Stuck in baby Rudin Proof of Theoem 8.1.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limsup-and-liminf

According to Rudin Since $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n^{\frac{1}{n}}=\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}n^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$ and $\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}|c_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}=R$,
$$\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}(n|c_n|)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}|c_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}=R.$$
Why is this reasonable?

Comment: Are we have any theorem such that $limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=a,limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n=b,\  then\ limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_nb_n=ab $?

Comment: You are using here: If $\lim x_n=A$ and $\limsup y_n=B$ where $A,B>0$, then $\limsup x_ny_n=AB$. (In fact, I think $A>0$ suffices here.) You can have a look here: [If $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n = a\in \mathbb{R}$ . Prove that $\limsup_{n\to \infty}a_n x_n=a\limsup_{n\to \infty}x_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1244661). (And you can probably find a few other similar posts.)

Comment: I think you at least need to specify the sign (if both sequences are negative, this doesn't always hold). Intuitively, if the sequences are positive, we should have $\lim\sup a_nb_n \leq ab$ (we can't guarantee equality - can you think of any counterexamples?)

Comment: Thank you for your answers, now I could search a theorem in Elementary analysis of Kenneth A.Ross.(Theorem 12.1 said that)

Answer (score 0):

Then following fact is used:

**Lemma.** *If $a_n\to a>0$ and $\limsup b_n=b\ge 0$, then $\limsup a_nb_n=ab$.*

*Proof.* It suffices to show the following:

(i) If a subsequence of $a_nb_n$ converges to $c$, then $c\le ab$.

(ii) There exists a subsequence of $a_nb_n$ converging to $ab$.

For (i), if $a_{n_k}b_{n_k}\to c$, then 
$$
b_{n_k}=\frac{1}{a_{n_k}}\cdot a_{n_k}b_{n_k}\to \frac{1}{a} \cdot c,
$$
and hence $\frac{c}{a}\le b$ or $c\le ab$.

Fot (ii), since $\limsup b_n=b$, there exists a subsequence $b_{n_k}\to b$ and hence  $a_{n_k}b_{n_k}\to ab$.