# Show that $\limsup_{n \to \infty}a_nb_n= \limsup_{n \to \infty}a_n \cdot \lim_{n \to \infty}b_n$

Tags: complex-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Let $\{a_n\}_{n \geq0}$ and $\{b_n\}_{n \geq0}$ be two real sequences and suppose that $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n=b \geq 0$ exist. Show that $$\limsup_{n \to \infty}a_nb_n= \limsup_{n \to \infty}a_n \cdot \lim_{n \to \infty}b_n$$

I am stacked on this problem. Could anyone give me a hint?

Comment: If $lim_n a_n b_n=\infty$ and $lim_n b_n=0$ then $(lim sup_n a_n)(lim_n b_n)=(\infty)\cdot 0$ which is undefinable. E.g, $a_n=2^n$ and $b_n=1/n$.

Comment: @user254665 So there is a mistake in the question? One argument more should be that $\{a_n\}_{n \geq 0}$ has to be bound?

Comment: Duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/113121/

Comment: $a_n$ bounded,  or that $lim_n  b_n>0$ .

Comment: @user254665 I don't understand your first comment