# Can we always conclude limit superior and limit inferior of $\langle a_n\rangle=\langle b_nc_n\rangle$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences, limsup-and-liminf

Suppose that $\langle b_n\rangle$ and $\langle c_n\rangle$ be two sequences which are bounded and we know their limit superiors and limit inferiors.If we define a new sequence $\langle a_n\rangle$ as $\langle a_n\rangle=\langle b_nc_n\rangle$.
My question is **"Can we always conclude limit superior and limit inferior of $\langle a_n\rangle$?**

Comment: No this is in general not possible, unless the limit of $b_n$ or $c_n$ exists. But, we can always get some upper bounds and lower bounds in terms of the liminf and limsups of the sequences.

Comment: For positive sequences, you can at least tell som upper and lower bound: $\liminf b_n \cdot \limsup c_n \le \limsup (b_nc_n) \le \limsup b_n \cdot \limsup c_n$. You can find more about one of these inequalities here: [lim sup inequality $\limsup ( a_n b_n ) \leq \limsup a_n \limsup b_n $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/113121)

Answer (score 0):

No.
Suppose
$b_{2n}=1,
b_{2n+1}=0,
c_{2n}=0,
c_{2n+1}=-1
$.
Then
$b_nc_n = 0$
for all $n$.