# Prove that a power series and its deriviative has the same convergence radius

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, power-series, limsup-and-liminf

Let $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n} $ be a power series. prove that

$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n},\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(n+1\right)a_{n+1}x^{n} $

has the same convergence radius.

So, let $ \limsup\sqrt[n]{|a_{n}|}=\beta $

It follows that $ \limsup\sqrt[n+1]{|a_{n+1}|}=\beta $ (**Im not sure about this argument, we'll sign it as (*) )**

Its enough to show that $ \limsup\sqrt[n]{\left(n+1\right)|a_{n+1}|}=\beta $

Let $ \limsup\sqrt[n]{\left(n+1\right)|a_{n+1}|}=\gamma $ and we'll show that $\beta=\gamma $

From the assumption above, we can find a subsequence such that $ \lim_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[n_{k}]{|a_{n_{k}}|}=\beta$

And we can notice that :

$ \lim_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[n_{k}]{\left(n_{k}+1\right)|a_{n_{k}+1}|}=\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(n_{k}+1\right)^{\frac{1}{n_{k}}}\cdot\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(|a_{n_{k}+1}|^{\frac{1}{n_{k}+1}}\right)^{\frac{n_{k}+1}{n_{k}}} $

and because of **(*)**

$ \lim_{k\to\infty}\left(n_{k}+1\right)^{\frac{1}{n_{k}}}\cdot\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(|a_{n_{k}+1}|^{\frac{1}{n_{k}+1}}\right)^{\frac{n_{k}+1}{n_{k}}}=\beta $

So $ \beta \leq \gamma $

Now, we'll take a subsequence such that $ \lim_{j\to\infty}\sqrt[n_{j}]{\left(n_{j}+1\right)|a_{n_{j}+1}}=\gamma $

And we'll notice that

$ \gamma=\lim_{j\to\infty}\sqrt[n_{j}]{\left(n_{j}+1\right)|a_{n_{j}+1}|}=\lim_{j\to\infty}\left(n_{j}+1\right)^{\frac{1}{n_{j}}}\cdot\lim_{j\to\infty}|a_{n_{j}+1}|^{\frac{1}{n_{j}}}=\lim_{j\to\infty}\left(|a_{n_{j}+1}|^{\frac{1}{n_{j}+1}}\right)^{\frac{n_{j+1}}{n_{j}}}=\gamma $

Therefore, because of **(*)**

$ \lim_{j\to\infty}|a_{n_{j}+1}|^{\frac{1}{n_{j}+1}}=\lim_{j\to\infty}|a_{n_{j}}|^{\frac{1}{n_{j}}}=\gamma $

And thus $ \gamma \leq \beta $ and we get that $ \gamma = \beta $

Now everything depend's on the validity of **(*)** So I hope you could tell me if it's okay and maybe help my justify it.

I feel like it's abuse of notation because $ a_{n_{k+1}}\neq a_{n_{k}+1} $ so  I dont know if my argument holds.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You don't say where your indices start, so I pick $1$.  Altering this is easy.

$$  \left( \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} \right)_{n \geq 1} = (|a_1|, \sqrt{a_2}, \sqrt[3]{a_3}, \dots )  \text{ and }  $$
$$  \left( \sqrt[n+1]{|a_{n+1}|} \right)_{n \geq 1} = (\sqrt{a_2}, \sqrt[3]{a_3}, \dots )  \text{,}  $$
so the second sequence is the subsequence of the first sequence formed by deleting the first term.  The limit you ask about is indifferent to any finite segment of the sequence not containing a maximum of the sequence, so the two limits agree as long as the first term is not a maximal term of the sequence.

Comment: So my proof is fine?

Comment: @Waizman : The Question does not ask about the proof, it asks about the seuqence and the subsequence having identical $\lim\sup$.

Comment: I know. But during the proof I used this argument on subsequences, and for thouse $n_k+1$ is not subsequence of $n_k. So can you tell if my proof is wrong?

Comment: @Waizman : It is not the case that the $\lim \sup$ of a subsequence is necessarily the same as the $\lim \sup$ of the sequence.  Consider the even index and odd index halves of the sequence that alternates between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: @Waizman :  Further, it appears that your question is not present in your Question, so I'm not sure what sort of Answer you believe is appropriate for the Question *as written*.

Comment: Ofcourse. I ment that I dont know if I can claim the same argument as you explained why the limits are rhe same in your main comment. Because $ a_n_{k+1} \neq a_{n_k+1} $

Comment: I just want to know if this proof is fine, Eric.

Comment: @Waizman : The Question is not tagged "proof-verification" and the closest approach to an actual question in the Question is "Now everything depend's on the validity of (*) So I hope you could tell me if it's okay and maybe help my justify it."  This Answer is completely responsive to the Question as written.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this general result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113121/lim-sup-inequality-limsup-a-n-b-n-leq-limsup-a-n-limsup-b-n) (the equality part), we indeed have:

$$ 
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{(n+1)|a_{n+1}|}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n+1}\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_{n+1}|} $$

You are basically attempting to prove it by choosing special (their limits are hitting the $\limsup$'s) subsequences on both sides, but in the process you set $\limsup$ of a sequence to $\limsup$ of one of its non-special sequences (which is wrong as stated in the comments on the other answer). The limit on non-special sequences might not even exist. I think you do this by assuming that the special subsequence for the product of sequences are also special for the individual sequences (and vice versa).

Slightly cleaner application of the general result:

$$ \sum_{n\geq 0} (n+1)a_{n+1} x^n = \sum_{n\geq 1} na_n x^{n-1}  $$

The convergence radius of $ \sum_{n\geq 1} na_n x^{n-1} $ is the same as the one of

$$ \sum_{n\geq 1} na_n x^{n} = x \sum_{n\geq 1} na_n x^{n-1}. $$

Then:

$$ 
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n|a_{n}|}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n}\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|} = \limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can you be please more specific? which of sequences I defined may not have a limit?

Comment: How do you know that $\lim_{j\to\infty}\sqrt[n_{j}]{\left(n_{j}+1\right)|a_{n_{j}+1}|}=\lim_{j\to\infty}\left(n_{j}+1\right)^{\frac{1}{n_{j}}}\cdot\lim_{j\to\infty}|a_{n_{j}+1}|^{\frac{1}{n_{j}}}$? Third limit might not exist.

Comment: From the assumption  $ \lim_{j\to\infty}\sqrt[n_{j}]{\left(n_{j}+1\right)|a_{n_{j}+1}|}=\gamma $ So, $ \lim_{j\to\infty}\left(n_{j}+1\right)^{\frac{1}{n_{j}}}|a_{n_{j}+1}|^{\frac{1}{n_{j}}}=\gamma $ and if $ \lim_{j\to\infty}|a_{n_{j}+1}|^{\frac{1}{n_{j}}} $ does not exists, we'll get a contradiction because the former limit wouldnt exist

Comment: because $ \lim_{j\to\infty}\left(n_{j}+1\right)^{\frac{1}{n_{j}}}=1 $

Comment: $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} 1/n \cdot \sin(n) $ exists, but one of the components doesn't have limit.

Comment: But none of them has the limit 1. Can you give a counter example for 2 sequences that one of them converges to 1?

Comment: I can't. Division formula says (limit of non-zero sequence in denominator is non-zero) that you are right.

Comment: So, I guess the follow-up question is: what do you do with $\lim_{j\to\infty}|a_{n_{j}+1}|^{\frac{1}{n_{j}}}$?