# What is the definition of limit superior/inferior of real function?

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_limit

Wikipedia has the definition for metric space, but it doesn't have a definition for extended real-field.

It just says, 'Limit inferior and limit superior of a real function are always well-defined in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$'.

In that sense, I don't think the definition for metric space covers real-valued functions. (Isolated points)

What's the definition it would be?

Comment: Related (to some extent) [About the notion of limsup and liminf](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49699/about-the-notion-of-limsup-and-liminf/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote:

> In that sense, I don't think the definition for metric space covers real-valued functions. (Isolated points)

If you are asking what metric you should take on $\mathbb R\cup\{\pm\infty\}$ so that the definition [for metric spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_limit#Functions_from_metric_spaces_to_metric_spaces) yields the correct definition for real function, then the answer is: Identify $\mathbb R\cup\{\pm\infty\}$ with $[0,1]$ via some order-preserving bijection. Transfer the metric from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R\cup\{\pm\infty\}$ using this bijection. Then the definition given in Wikipedia article for function to an ordered metric space gives as a special case the definition for functions to $\overline{\mathbb R}$.

Here is link to the [current revision](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior&oldid=520632246#Functions_from_metric_spaces_to_metric_spaces) of the Wikipedia article linked above. (Just in case it changes substantially in the future.)

---

EDIT: (In response to [the comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252137/what-is-the-definition-of-limit-superior-inferior-of-real-function/252162#comment554391_252162) asking about $\limsup\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ for a function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$.)

$\limsup_{x\to a} f(x)$ is defined even if the value of $f$ at the point $a$ is not defined. If we follow the definition from Wikipedia, we should look at punctured neighborhood of $\infty$. The balls around $\infty$ are the intervals of the form $(x,\infty)$. So we get
$$\limsup\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \sup\{f(a); a>x\} = \inf\limits_{x\in\mathbb R} \sup\{f(a); a>x\}.$$

Comment: Then, what's the meaning of "$\limsup_{x\to\infty} f(x)$" where $f$ is a map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Also, wikipedia says, "$Y$ should be an ordered set". Does this mean $Y$ should be well-ordered? Or just fully-ordered? I guess, in ZF, to define limit inferior of a function from $X$ to $Y$ where $X,Y$ are topological spaces, $Y$ should be Dedekind-complete field. Am i correct?

Comment: You need that the suprema appearing in the definition of $\limsup$ exist. A complete lattice should be enough; perhaps this can be weakened. (I am not sure.) [Least-upper-bound property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-upper-bound_property) (Dedekind completeness) should work. To be honest, I never needed $\limsup$ in something different than $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R\cup\{\pm\infty\}$.

Comment: Martin, then could we write $\limsup_{n->\infty}f_n(x)$ equivalent to $\forall_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\exists_{k\geq n} f_k(x)$ ?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. To be honest, I am not sure how to understand what you wrote. If some further clarifications are needed, we can [take it into chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/14150/2017/8/9).

Comment: @MartinSleziak I took it into chat! =)

Answer (score 5):

Say one considers a function $f:(0,+\infty)\to\mathbb R$ and one wants to determine the limsup/liminf of $f$ at $0$. Then one would define $g(t)=\sup\{f(x)\mid0\lt x\lt t\}$, $h(t)=\inf\{f(x)\mid0\lt x \lt t\}$, and
$$
\limsup\limits_{x\to0}f(x)=\inf\{g(t)\mid t\gt0\}=\lim\limits_{t\to0}g(t),
$$
and
$$
\liminf\limits_{x\to0}f(x)=\sup\{h(t)\mid t\gt0\}=\lim\limits_{t\to0}h(t).
$$
Example: $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$ for every $x\gt0$, then $g(t)=+1$ and $h(x)=-1$ for every $t\gt0$ hence $\limsup\limits_{x\to0}f(x)=+1$ and $\liminf\limits_{x\to0}f(x)=-1$.

Similar but more involved: if $f(x)=(2+x^2\cos(1/x))\sin(1/x)$ for every $x\gt0$, then $\limsup\limits_{x\to0}f(x)=+2$ and $\liminf\limits_{x\to0}f(x)=-2$.

Comment: Let $a_n:=\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi}$. Then $f(a_n)=2$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$. So, $2\leq g(t)$ for any positive $t$. So, $2\leq\inf\{g(t)\mid 0<t\}.$ Let $\epsilon$ be any positive real number. Since $\left|\left(2+x^2\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right|\leq\left|2+x^2\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right|\leq 2+x^2$ and $\lim_{x\to +0} 2+x^2=2$, $g(t)<2+\epsilon$ for some positive $t$. So, $\inf\{g(t)\mid 0<t\}<2+\epsilon.$ So, $\inf\{g(t)\mid 0<t\}=2.$

Comment: I cannot find the definition of limit superior of real function in any calculus books of mine. Why?

Answer (score -2):

Just consider the function

$$ f(x) = \frac{|x|}{x}.$$

Can you determine the limsup and the liminf as $x \to 0$ of this function? See [here](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Limit+superior+and+limit+inferior) for the definition.