# limit supremum that I have not seen before - for $t\to0^+$

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Suppose I have a function $f(t) = 0$ for $t \leq 0$ and $f(t) = 2t\sin(1/t) - \cos(1/t)$ for $t > 0$. I want to show that $f$ is discontinuous at $0$ by showing that $\limsup_{t \to 0^+} f(t) = 1$ and $\liminf_{t \to 0^+} f(t) = -1.$ (as per the question.)

Now I have seen $\limsup_{n \to \infty}$ but not have seen $\limsup_{t \to 0^+}$. So I am not sure but below I have given an attempt at this problem.

Since $\lim_{t \to 0^+}2t\sin{1/t} = 0$, for $t < \epsilon$ (some very small number), we have 
$$
f(t) = 2t\sin(1/t) - \cos(1/t) = -\cos(1/t)
$$
Now since we know $-1 \leq -\cos(1/t) \leq 1$, $\limsup_{t \to 0^+} f(t) = 1$ and $\liminf_{t \to 0^+} f(t) = -1.$

Is this plausible? Thanks.

Comment: You seem to have the right idea.  You'd need to actually show that $cos(\frac{1}{t})$ attains $-1$ and $1$ on the interval $(0, \epsilon)$ for all $\epsilon > 0$

Comment: Do you have to do this problem using limit superior and limit inferior?

Comment: @JDZ yeah, the question requires that I do it this way.

Comment: The def'n of  $\lim \sup_{t\to )^+}f(t)$ is  : For only positive$ t$ let $h(t)=\sup \{f(u): u\in (0,t]\}$ and then $\lim \sup_{t\to 0^+}$  is  $\lim_{t\to 0; t>0} h(t)$. You have the right idea. Look at $f(x)$ when  $x=1/\pi n $ for natural number n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several definition of $\limsup_{n\to\infty} x_n$. It should not be very difficult to take the definition you are used to and get from this the corresponding definition for $t\to0^+$.

One of the definitions of limit superior of a sequence is
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} x_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sup_{k\ge n} x_k.$$

In your situation you would get the corresponding definition in the form
$$\limsup_{t\to0^+} f(t) = \lim_{t\to0^+} \sup_{s\in(0,t]} f(s).$$

Similarly as for sequences, you can get other equivalent definitions of limit superior for $t\to0^+$.

All these various notions of limit superior can be understood as special case of limit superior of a [net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_%28mathematics%29).
However, the notion of net is only taught later in more advanced courses. (You will typically encounter it in a course on general topology.) See, for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/definitions-for-limsup-and-liminf), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/49852) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188722/limsups-of-nets).

---

For you special case you can notice that $\lim\limits_{t\to0^+} 2t\sin\frac1t =0$. Therefore
$$\limsup\limits_{t\to0^+} \left(2t\sin\frac1t + \cos\frac1t\right) = 
\lim\limits_{t\to0^+} 2t\sin\frac1t + \limsup\limits_{t\to0^+} \cos\frac1t = 
\limsup\limits_{t\to0^+} \cos\frac1t = 1.$$
(We have used property analogous to the property shown here fore sequences: [How to prove $\limsup (x_{n}+y_{n})=\lim x_{n}+\limsup y_{n}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33888/how-to-prove-limsup-x-ny-n-lim-x-n-limsup-y-n))

---

To see that $\limsup\limits_{t\to0^+} \cos\frac1t = 1$ we could simply observe that:

- We have $\cos\frac1t\le1$, therefore also $\limsup\limits_{t\to0^+} \cos\frac1t \le 1$.
- We can find a sequence $t_n$ such that $t_n\to0^+$ and $\cos\frac1{t_n}=1$. (Simply take $t_n$'s such that $\frac1{t_n}=2\pi n$, i.e., $t_n=\frac1{2\pi n}$.) Therefore $\limsup\limits_{t\to0^+} \cos\frac1t \ge 1$.

Comment: How do we know with certainty that $\limsup_{t \to 0^+}\cos(1/t) = 1$?

Comment: @turtle I have tried to add a more detailed explanation to my post.

Comment: I am sorry, why $\cos(1/t_n) = 0?$

Comment: @turle My bad. Corrected now. (It should have been 1 instead of 0.)

Comment: wow,, great answer. thank you.